# "multiple template parameter lists are not allowed"?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm coding a simple class to manage some code detours.

The class:

```
class CDetourManager {
public:

    CDetourManager() {}

    ~CDetourManager() {}

    template<convention_type tp, typename retn, typename ...args>
    VOID AddDetour( Detour<tp, retn, args...>* d ) {
        m_Detours.push_back( d );
    }

private:
    template<convention_type tp, typename retn, typename ...args>
    std::vector<Detour<tp, retn, args...>* > m_Detours;
};
```

But im getting a error:
`Error 1 error C3857: 'CDetourManager::m_Detours': multiple template parameter lists are not` allowed

Does anyone know what I could do to get rid of that error? It's my first time using templates so I'm kind of lost here :(

Comment: That can not work, `m_Detours` has no distinct type.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to store a `vector` of pointers to `Detour`s. Since each specialisation of `Detour` has a different (and unrelated) type, this is not possible directly. However, if you make the `Detour` template inherit from some `IDetour` interface which provides the required functions to operate on a `Detour`, then you can write `AddDetour` as:

```
void AddDetour(IDetour *d) {
    m_Detours.push_back(d);
}
```

and `m_Detours` as:

```
std::vector<IDetour *> m_Detours;
```